# GPG warns about unprotected subkeys while using monkeysphere

Tags: ssh, pgp

Issuing `monkeysphere subkey-to-shh-agent` GPG warns me:

```
gpg: about to export an unprotected subkey
```

then it asks for the passphrase and everything works fine.

What's the meaning of "export an unprotected subkey"? What are the security issues related to this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with monkeysphere and ASCII armoring in gpg:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.monkeysphere/401

> Chatted with dkg on irc, turns out monkeysphere just doesn't like "armor" in one's ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf - dkg seemed to think this was a bug that wouldn't be that hard to fix.

ASCII Armoring is just a term for binary to text encoding.
[Wikipedia article on binary to text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding)

GPG is just complaining that the exported key lacks this encoding, which the comment from the mailing list backs up if the author isn't using it elsewhere.

Comment: I think this explanation is wrong. That thread is not about the "gpg: about to export an unprotected subkey" warning, but about the "This is not an OpenPGP packet" error (mentionned in the title).